# Does LSTM keep its state between subsequent samples in the training process?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm not sure if I understood well how LSTM works.
I know that the LSTM layers keep an internal state. But I'm not sure if this state is maintained between subsequent samples during the training process.
That is, changing the ordering of training samples in the same batch would produce different outcomes in the training process?